# Python, VK API: как проверить на подписку пользователей на сообщество?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Как проверить, подписан ли человек на моё сообщество?

Этот код проверяет, подписан ли я на какую-либо группу, а как быть в обратном направлении, т.е. как узнать, подписан ли определённый человек на мою группу?

```
import vk
def Authorization():  # Авторизация пользователя
    return vk.API(vk.AuthSession(app_id='***',
                                user_login='***',
                                user_password='***',
                                scope='groups'))

def foo(session):
    if session.groups.isMember(group_id = 'Group id'): # Проверяем является ли пользователь участником сообщества
        return 'Вы уже подписаны.'
    session.groups.join(group_id = 'Group id')  # ID Группы. Подписываемся 
    return 'Спасибо за подписку {0}'.format(session.users.get()[0]['first_name'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(foo(Authorization()))
```

Comment: В `groups.isMember` добавить параметр `user_id=ID` где ID - ид человека. Документация: https://vk.com/dev/groups.isMember

Comment: Ну в скобки, через запятую,  пробовал, в моём случае было так,
    if session.groups.isMember(group_id = 'gamedevcube',user_id = 'olya_tuchka')  Не вышло. Не работает так, если бы доки, так просто помогли бы, сюда бы не  обращался

Comment: Вы так и написали в ид - olya_tuchka ?

Comment: Да, это же так сказать публичный адрес, но попытки постановки id*** и прочих цифирок, дали аналогичный результат. Тобеж нулевой

Comment: Я думаю Вы делаете что-то не так. ИД нужно ставить только цифрами.  В `users.get()` тоже нужно добавить этот параметр.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, разобрался, нашёл,  в чём была проблема, я на самом деле не правильно запускал сессию. usr_id -  передаётся при вызове функции

Вот, у меня так, кому-то может пригодится:

```
def user_aprove(user_id, token):
    if api.groups.isMember(access_token = token, group_id = 'komnata_risovak',user_id = user_id):# Проверяем является ли пользователь участником сообщества
        return 1
    return 0
```

Comment: Я же вам это в комментариях писал... и кстати, else можно заменить на просто `return 0` так как функция после первого же `return` прекращает работу

Comment: Согласен, ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: Поправил ответ, чтобы было совсем компактно.

Comment: Можно еще лямбдой сделать :)